# Running into `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError` while using JSON Array Data Source formed using Karate.mapWithKey

Tags: karate

I am trying to pass a JSON Array Data Source to form a dynamic `path` for my API tests.
I am converting an existing Array (which I get back from another APIand JS function) to a JSON Array using `karate.mapWithKey` in the same feature file.

When I print the value of `input`, I do see a properly formatted list of objects as below

```
[
  {
    "keyUUID": "1234"
  },
  {
    "keyUUID": "5678"
  }
]
```

However, when I run the whole feature, I am seeing an error as `org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "input" is not defined`

```
Feature: Data-Driven Feature


Scenario Outline: looping over list of json objects
  * def keys = ['1234','5678']
  * def input = karate.mapWithKey(keys,'keyUUID')
  * print input
  * When path is <name>
   Examples:
    | input |
```

Am I missing something here?
I tried reading through a json file , which works fine but the json array of objects created using `mapWithKey` always gives an error.

Comment: impossible to diagnose with the lack of info. follow this process if you can: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve it after moving the `input` [json array of objects creation] from within `scenario outline` to `Background`

```
Feature: Data-Driven Feature

Background:
  * def keys = ['1234','5678']
  * def input = karate.mapWithKey(keys,'keyUUID')
  * print input

Scenario Outline: looping over list of json objects
  * When path is <name>
   Examples:
    | input |
```

The reference error I was receiving earlier for `input` is resolved now.